# How can I stack analysis variables on vertically in a PROC REPORT?

Tags: sas

I am trying to stack multiple variables vertically in a PROC REPORT. I am tied to PROC REPORT over TABULATE or FREQ, so a solution using REPORT would be preferable.

I've tested out other solutions, but unable to find success using my data.

```
proc format library = library ;
   value AGE
      1 = '18 to 29'  
      2 = '30 to 45'  
      3 = '46 to 64'  
      4 = '65 and over'  
      9 = 'NA' ;
   value SEX
      1 = 'Male'  
      2 = 'Female'  
      9 = 'NA' ;
   value Q16F
      1 = 'EXCELLENT'  
      2 = 'VERY GOOD'  
      3 = 'GOOD'  
      4 = 'FAIR'  
      5 = 'POOR'  
      8 = 'DON''T KNOW'  
      9 = 'NA/REFUSED' ;

DATA CHSS2017_sashelp (keep = q16 sex age);
SET CHSS2017.CHSS2017_sashelp;
FORMAT       q16 q16f.;
FORMAT       sex SEX.;
FORMAT       age AGE.;
RUN;

proc report data = CHSS2017_sashelp nowindows headline;
columns sex n, (q16);
define sex / group;
define q16 / across;
run;
```

The expected result would be a stacked REPORT table with multiple variables:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV3jw.png)

Comment: Show an example of what type of report you are trying to generate.  Can you use other steps to generate the data for the report into a new dataset and then use PROC REPORT to display it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with repeated headings/variable names then you can use two report procedures. See code below, I have used sample sas data and customized the formats a bit:

```
proc format ;
   value AGE
      1-10 = '1 to 10'  
      11-12 = '11 to 12'  
      13-High = '13 and over'  
      ;
   value $SEXv
      'M' = 'Male'  
      'F' = 'Female'  
      ;
   value Q16F
      1 = 'EXCELLENT'  
      2 = 'VERY GOOD'  
      3 = 'GOOD'  
      4 = 'FAIR'  
      5 = 'POOR'  
      8 = 'DON''T KNOW'  
      9 = 'NA/REFUSED' ;
run;

%macro RandBetween(min, max);
   (&min + floor((1+&max-&min)*rand("uniform")))
%mend;

data class;
 set sashelp.class;
   q16 = %RandBetween(1, 9);
   FORMAT       q16 q16f.;
   FORMAT       sex $SEXv.;
   FORMAT       age AGE.;
run;

proc report data = class nowindows headline;
columns age n, (q16);
define age/ group;
define q16 / across;
run;

proc report data = class nowindows headline;
columns sex n, (q16);
define sex / group;
define q16 / across;
run;
```

the macro RandBetween is only for this code, you don't have to use it

Comment: I need the two proc report statements merged into one so that it's one output with multiple variables, stacked vertically, rather than two.